# Why arrow wings are more efficient than delta wings?

Tags: aerodynamics, supersonic, delta-wing

From page 29 of this slide (https://archive.aoe.vt.edu/mason/Mason_f/SupersonicPres.pdf), an arrow wing has higher lift slope and lower induced drag slope than a delta wing with a straight trailing edge, all else being equal. Could anyone explain the mechanism of trailing edge sweep angle vs. lift and drag?

Comment: A short clarification while waiting for an answer: what you see in that plot is the *slope* of the lift coefficient. Higher slope means that the aircraft is more sensitive to changes of angle of attack but does not imply that the maximum lift coefficient is higher.

Comment: Arrow wing??? That looks like a swept delta to me.

Comment: Sophit: I was asssuming these two wings don’t generate much lift around 0 degree AOA. Then if we integrate Cla from 0 degree AOA, a higher slope everywhere results in a higher lift. But you are right, I shouldn’t make that assumption in the first place.

Comment: @SOAR1123: I was thinking if the fact that the coefficients look better on the arrow wing isn't just a side effect of the nondimensionalisation with the smaller wing surface of the arrow wing in respect to the delta wing 

Comment: @sophit: On previous page it stated “pressure at TE don’t have to come together in supersonic like in subsonic”, leading me to believe it might has something to do with some shockwave / TE interactions. Besides, if two wings (with presumably same airfoils) have different Cl (or Cla), there must be some 3D effect causing different pressure distribution. So I personally feel its not a problem with wing area.

Comment: “Previous page” refers to slide 28 of the document, that is.